# How can I change Ticketmaster login Header text in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sdk

I want to change header of ticketmaster login header text . While I am passing **displayName** as empty string ("") in *PresenceSDK* , my application is crashing.
 **[image: So any other place to change ??]**

> current text : *Sign in with your Office account or Ticketmaster account*
>
> Expected :  *Sign in with your Ticketmaster account*

`PresenceSDK.getPresenceSDK().setConfig(consumerKey: consumerKey, displayName: "Office account");`